# Combining two "foreach" loops

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

A little background on my feature:

We've built an application that allows you to create and share something, the final step is sharing it with other users.

I have a view that prints out all the users and a checkbox next to each name. Using AJAX, if you check or uncheck a box it inserts into a database table the user id and the id of the shared item.

Thus, I need to join two tables to see who has had the item shared with them. One table holds the item then the other table holds who its been shared with.

At the moment, I have a foreach loop that pulls out all the user ID's that have been shared:

```
<?php foreach($shared_user as $shared_user):?>
        <?= $shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)]; ?><br />
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then, a foreach loop that pulls out all the users and their check boxes:

```
<?php foreach($users1 as $user):?>
<?php $checked = ($user->id == $shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)])? 'checked' : '' ;   ?>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="template_permissions" data-id="<?= $user->id?>"   <?= $checked ?> /><?= $user->email ?></label>
```

You'll see in the above foreach, I did:

```
$user->id == $shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)])? 'checked' : '' ;
```

Which is saying, if the shared user ID is equal to the users ID, apply "checked" to the input. This is working great, but only for ONE user rather then looping through them all.

Everything is sharing and working correctly, however only ONE checkbox will be checked, instead of all the users being checked if they've been shared.

I believe I need to somehow combine these two for each loops, it's clearly only pulling in the last person whose been shared and checking their box.

I've tried combining these two loops for about a day now, can anyone lend a hand?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is how the variables are created from within my controller:

```
load_model('user_model', 'users');
    $users = $this->users->users_by_company($company_id);


    load_model('template_user_model', 'template_users');
    $shared_users = $this->template_users->get_many_by('template_id', $template_id);

    $this->data['shared_user'] = $shared_users;

    $this->data['shared_user_emails'] = $this->user_model->dropdown('id');
```

Not 100% sure what set_default does, but this shouldn't be an issue when trying to solve this...

**EDIT**

This is what is contained in the variables using print_r as requested:

Using:

```
<p>shared_user_emails:</p>
        <?php print_r($shared_user_emails); ?>

        <p>shared_user:</p>
        <?php print_r($shared_user); ?>

        <p>User:</p>
        <?php print_r($user); ?>
```

Produced:

**shared_user_emails:**

```
Array (
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [17] => 17
    [19] => 19
)
```

**shared_user:**

```
stdClass Object (
    [template_id] => 58
    [user_id] => 3
)
```

**User:**

```
stdClass Object (
    [id] => 19
    [name] => Steve
    [title] =>
    [phone] =>
    [ext] =>
    [email] => mike+whatev@fake.com
    [active] => 1
    [group_id] => 3
    [group] => users
)
```

And: `$shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)]` prints out "3"

Comment: What are the contents of `$shared_user`, `$shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)]` and `$user`? What does `set_default` do?

Comment: Added what you needed above, not entirely sure what set_default does but that shouldn't come into play when solving this

Comment: That's not very helpful as it doesn't show the contents of the variables. Paste `print_r()` result for each of them.

Comment: All set, let me know if you needed any others...

Comment: **$shared_user as $shared_user** this is why it only does the first user I think

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem, it's only comparing 1 instead of doing all the users, I think I need to implement an array or something? Can't figure it out ><

Comment: I mean shouldn't it be foreach $shared_users as $shared_user? Possible mistype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely did a typo in your foreach.

In your controller you do this:

```
$shared_users = $this->template_users->get_many_by('template_id', $template_id);

$this->data['shared_user'] = $shared_users;
```

Note that the variable `$shared_users` is not assigned under this name to the template data, but the last `s` is missing.

In your template:

```
<?php foreach($shared_user as $shared_user):?>
```

The variable `$shared_user` is used twice! This overwrites the list of users (left variable) from your controller with the current user in this list (right variable after "as"). Which is ok inside this loop, because foreach creates a copy of the array internally to avoid confusion here, but after the loop ends, you do not have access to the list later on, because the last user in the list overwrote the list.

Do not use the same variable twice in a foreach loop. It always looks like it is an error, even though it might not be one. Since you are complaining about stuff not working, this one is an error, and it starts in your controller. There is no reason not to name the list "users", and the single user "user".

So you want to loop over all shared users. For each of these you want to output:

```
<?= $shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)]; ?><br />
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="template_permissions" data-id="<?= $user->id?>"   <?= $checked ?> /><?= $user->email ?></label>
```

This would theoretically result in something like this HTML:

```
3<br />
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="template_permissions" data-id="19" checked />mike+whatev@fake.com</label>
```

But only if this "mike" is on the list of shared users, otherwise the checkbox will not be checked.

I think you just need to extend the first loop beyond the second. Currently they do not overlap, so in addition to you incorrectly using the first foreach loop due to the typo, you also did the two loops one after the other.

But you really do not need the second, inner loop. The question you have at this point: Does the users array contain the shared user id? There is a PHP function for this: `in_array()`. This makes it more clear what you want.

```
<?php $checked = (in_array($shared_user_emails[set_default($shared_user->user_id)], $user->id))? 'checked' : '' ; ?>
```